# Wkhtmltopdf output changes when changing IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, encoding, wkhtmltopdf

We are trying to create some functions that accepts a streamreader consisting of a memorystream of and xml and xslt combined to create a pdf through wkhtml and then output it as a pdf through a memorystream to avoid saving any temporary files to disk. When we use IIS Express we get a fully valid pdf with no encoding problems as output, but when we use IIS Local the pdf that is returned have encoding problems. Anyone experienced any similar issues? We are using encoding page 850.

```
private static void GeneratePdfFromStream()
    {
        var msXml = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Constants.FilesFakturaXml));
        var msXslt = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Constants.FilesFakturaXslt));
        var ms = XmlTransformer.XmlAndXslToHtml(msXml, msXslt);
        File.WriteAllBytes(Constants.FilesResultHtml, ms.ToArray());

        var pdfStream = Printer.GeneratePdf(new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.GetEncoding(850), false));
        File.WriteAllBytes(Constants.FilesResultPdf, pdfStream.ToArray());
    }



public static MemoryStream GeneratePdf(StreamReader html)
    {
        html.BaseStream.Position = 0;
        var pdf = new MemoryStream();
        using (html)
        {
            Process p;
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                Arguments = Switches() + string.Format("-q -n {0} ", WkHtmlSettings.DisableSmartShrinking) + " - -"
            };
            p = Process.Start(psi);
            try
            {
                if (p != null)
                {
                    var stdin = p.StandardInput;
                    stdin.AutoFlush = true;
                    stdin.Write(html.ReadToEnd());

                    stdin.Dispose();
                }
                CopyStream(p.StandardOutput.BaseStream, pdf);
                Console.WriteLine(  p.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding.CodePage);
                p.StandardOutput.Close();
                pdf.Position = 0;
                p.WaitForExit(10000);
                return pdf;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (p != null) p.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, when using `XslCompiledTransform` and `XmlWriter` you must include settings for the writer to `OmitXmlDeclaration = true` and `Encoding = "What encoding you need"` as shown below:

```
  private MemoryStream _XmlAndXslToHtml(string sXml, string sXslt)
    {
        var myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
        var style = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(sXslt));
        var data = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(sXml));
        var retval = new MemoryStream();


        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        var output = XmlWriter.Create(retval, settings);
        //output.Settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

        myXslTrans.Load(style);
        myXslTrans.Transform(data, output);
        return retval;
    }
```